# Cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c, string, pointers, casting, warnings

```
client_t *client_create_no_window(char *in, char *out); 

// ...

char line[50];
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
{
    line[pos] = c;
    pos++;
}
pos=0;
```

then I try to call the function `client_create_no_window` by first doing

```
char* first = (char*) line[1];
char* second= (char*) line[2];
client_create_no_window(first, second);
```

I keep getting the error casting to pointer from integer of different size. I've looked at some of the previous posts on these but still cant understand why this is going on

Comment: yes sorry about that. just a typo. i will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char line[50];
```

defines an array of characters. Second character (`line[1]`) is stored in the memory at address that can be retrieved by using the *"address of"* operator (`&`): `&line[1]`.

```
char* second = (char*) line [1];
```

takes the second character (`line[1]`) and casts it to the pointer to `char`, which is incorrect. Pointer to the second character should be initialized by using the address, where this character resides:

```
char* second = &line[1];
```

Comment: -1, the first and second characters really aren't at those indices.

Comment: i know that line[0] is the first. i actually name variables zero, first. i know it's weird. it helps me remember

Comment: @user1665569: Second character is stored at index 1. That's fact that should be known by everyone, so calling it "first" character and then calling first character "zero" character might be confusing, I wouldn't do that :)

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
char*first = (char*) lines[1];
```

takes the *character* at `lines[1]`, converts it through a forced cast to `char *` (pointer to character, i.e. an address), and stores it in the character pointer `first`.

This is wrong, since characters are not addresses this assignment makes no sense.

What you want is probably the address of that character, which you can get by using the "address of" operator, `&`:

```
char *first = &lines[1];
```

which can also be written using pointer arithmetic as:

```
char *first = lines + 1;
```

Note, however, that C indexes from zero, so the first character is really at `lines[0]`:

```
char *first = &lines[0];
```

and the *second* is at `lines[1]`:

```
char *second = &lines[1];
```

Comment: i know that line[0] is the first. i actually name variables zero, first, and so on. i know it's weird, but it helped me remember the positions. thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm sure it's just a typo, but you declared `char lines[]` instead of `char line[]`. Second, did you want to put the address of `line[0]` into `first`? That would be:

```
char *first = line;
```

Or

```
char *first = &line[0];
```

Similarly:

```
char *second = &line[1];
```

Notice the first and second characters are at indexes 0 and 1, respectively.

Comment: i know that line[0] is the first. i actually name variables zero, first, and second. i know it's weird. it helps me remember

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows ( assume you are really trying to assign the pointer to the value of line[1] and line[2]).  If you want to point the the address of line[1] and line[2] you would do the &line[] as describe above and you will not have to use reinterpret_cast to stop the warning messages about size:

```
line[1] = 2;
line[2] = 0x234234;

char* first = reinterpret_cast<char *>(line[1]);
char* second= reinterpret_cast<char *>(line[2]);
client_create_no_window(first, second);
```

The first will be pointing to 0x000002
The second will be pointing to 0x234234

The reinterpret_cast take the value and casts it to the type and ***size of pointer*** given.  In the older compilers just doing the char *ptr = (char *)23 was good enough but the new compilers know a int (23 would be stored in a int) is not the size of a pointer (normally 64 bits) and it generates the warning message.  reinterpret_cast fixes that.